# javascript function and Logical operation

Tags: javascript, function

Why this line:

```
true &&  function() {console.log("aaa");}()
```

print

> aaa
>       undefined

but 
this line:

```
true ||  function() {console.log("aaa")}()
```

print

> true

I am very curious what's going on?
Why the function executed?

Comment: The function is executed because there are brackets at the end of your function. Try `true &&  function() {console.log("aaa");}`, aaa is not displayed.

Comment: why  only  function() {console.log("aaa")}() is Syntax error , while add "true && ", the funciton executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter `true && false` and result will be `false`. This means it is checking both the conditions and printing second condition.

Enter `true || false` and result will be `true`. This means that as soon as first condition evaluates to true it is not checking second condition and printing the first.

This explains what gets printed.

**Your first case:**
When you enter `true &&  function() {console.log("aaa");}()` it is evaluating second condition as well, and since your second condition is a callable function [*you are using `()` in the end*], its result i.e. "aaa" is printed.
Don't use `()` in the end i.e. enter `true &&  function() {console.log("aaa");}` and the result will be your second condition `function () {console.log("aaa");}`

**Your second case:**
When you enter `true ||  function() {console.log("aaa")}()` your first condition itself becomes true, so not evaluating second condition, hence only true is printed.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is evaluating both conditions since the second argument (the anonymous function) is ...well anonymous its undefined. 
The  `||` operator just evaluates to true on his first argument here (the `true`) hence it just prints `true`

Answer (score 1):

It is because `&&` operator is logical conjunction (`and`). Both of the operands need to be `true` for the statement to be `true`.

Meanwhile `||` is logical disjunction (`or`). Even when only one operand is `true`, it will be `true`.

When logical disjunciton (`or`) finds first operand to be true, there is no need to look any further and it can just return true.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the && logical operation checks for two expressions to evaluate to true, the || operator just needs one to be true. So in the first case, since the first expression evaluates to true, it checks for the other expression (the function) and that is why the function runs. In the second case, the first expression evaluates to true and thats all it needs so it stops there.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `&&` and `||` operations use [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). It stops evaluation as soon as the result is fully determined and does not evaluate the rest.

For example, change your first sample to:

```
false &&  function() {console.log("aaa");}()
```